# Receiving 'Error: Cannot find module' using browserify, gulp, react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, reactjs, browserify

So I've been playing around with React.js, gulp and browserify. Everything works great until I try to require a module in my `main.js` file. I am requiring components/modules in other files with no problem (see below), but when I try to require one in my `main.js` file, I receive the following error when running `gulp serve`:

> Error: Cannot find module './components/Feed' from
>   '/Users/kevin/Documents/MyWork/web/react/app/src/js'
>       at /Users/kevin/Documents/MyWork/web/react/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
>       at load (/Users/kevin/Documents/MyWork/web/react/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
>       at onex (/Users/kevin/Documents/MyWork/web/react/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
>       at /Users/kevin/Documents/MyWork/web/react/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
>       at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

If I remove the require (for Feed.js) statement from `main.js`, everything compiles and gets put in the appropriate `dist` folder and runs fine (except for react.js complaining about a missing module, of course).

Firstly, my folder structure looks like this:

```
app
│-- gulpfile.js
│-- package.json
│
└───src
│   │
│   ├───js
│       │-- main.js
│       └───components
│            │-- Feed.js
│            │-- FeedList.js
│            │-- FeedItem.js
│            │-- FeedForm.js
│            │-- ShowAddButton.js
│            └
│   
└───dist
```

My gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    open = require("gulp-open"),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    reactify = require('reactify'),
    source = require("vinyl-source-stream"),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    port = process.env.port || 3031;

// browserify and transform JSX
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var b = browserify();
    b.transform(reactify);
    b.add('./app/src/js/main.js');
    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/dist/js'));
});

// launch browser in a port
gulp.task('open', function(){
    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:' + port,
    };
    gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(open('', options));
});

// live reload server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: 'app',
        port: port,
        livereload: true
    });
});

// live reload js
gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/dist/**/*.js')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

// live reload html
gulp.task('html', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/*.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

// watch files for live reload
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/dist/js/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch('app/index.html', ['html']);
    gulp.watch('app/src/js/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify']);

gulp.task('serve', ['browserify', 'connect', 'open', 'watch']);
```

My main.js file looks like this:

```
var React = require('react'),
    Feed = require('./components/Feed');

React.renderComponent(
    <Feed />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The Feed.js file looks like:

```
var React = require('react');
var FeedForm = require('./FeedForm');
var ShowAddButton = require('./ShowAddButton');
var FeedForm = require('./FeedForm');
var FeedList = require('./FeedList');

var Feed = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        var FEED_ITEMS = [
            { key: '1', title: 'Just something', description: 'Something else', voteCount: 49 },
            { key: '2', title: 'Some more stuff', description: 'Yeah!', voteCount: 34 },
            { key: '3', title: 'Tea is good', description: 'yepp again', voteCount: 15 },
        ];

        return {
            items: FEED_ITEMS
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <ShowAddButton />
                </div>

                <FeedForm />

                <br />
                <br />

                <FeedList items={this.state.items} />
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = Feed;
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something really simple...but I've been at this for hours and can't seem to crack it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Obviously I'm not posting the code for the other components for the sake of being as brief as possible...but they aren't the problem).

Comment: `var Feed.js`? Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry...yes...corrected.

Comment: Can you please create a github repo with all the code? I created a project with the code you provided and it built correctly.

Comment: @SteveLacy Alright...github repo is here https://github.com/kevindeleon/react-test

This is basically some test code from a lesson I found online, but that's the exact code that I am running on my system that is failing for me.  OS X yosemite, if it makes any difference.

Comment: @SteveLacy -- also...obviously one would need to run `npm i` to install all needed node_modules....but I assume anyone reading this already likely knows that.

Comment: Ah, with the correct answer below, I created the files witthout the space in the name by manually creating them, thus my build worked

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your filenames are not what you think they are. Note this:

```
$ find app -type f | awk '{print "_"$0"_"}'
_app/dist/js/main.js_
_app/index.html_
_app/src/js/components/Feed.js _
_app/src/js/components/FeedForm.js _
_app/src/js/components/FeedItem.js_
_app/src/js/components/FeedList.js_
_app/src/js/components/ShowAddButton.js_
_app/src/js/main.js_
```

Your `Feed.js` file is actually `Feed.js<SPACE>`. Same for `FeedForm.js`. Renaming them makes your example repo build fine.

Comment: Holy crap man...thanks so much!  I have no idea how that happened.  You saved me hours!  I feel like a goon. :(

Comment: Wow! I'm very curious how you noticed this :-)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand If I had to guess...he probably just had a hunch and then ran the command he left above (`$ find app -type f | awk '{print "_"$0"_"}'`) to confirm.

Comment: I got lucky. I was typing in the file name and `zsh`s tab completion completed the filename with a space at the end, then I ran that command above to see if there were any others.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with code:

```
var React = require('react');
var FeedForm = require('./FeedForm.jsx');
var ShowAddButton = require('./ShowAddButton.jsx');
var FeedForm = require('./FeedForm.jsx');
var FeedList = require('./FeedList.jsx');
```

My issues resolved just after adding file extention(.jsx)

Thanks
Sulok

Comment: Explanation please...?

Comment: his explanation is that you need to explicitly specify the file extensions. worked for me.

Comment: @s2t2 in gulpfile.js you can specify `var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['./scripts/jsx/app.jsx'], 
        transform: [reactify],
       extensions: ['.jsx'],
        debug: true, 
        cache: {}, 
        packageCache: {}, 
        fullPaths: true 
    });`     **extensions property is important** then you  can remove .jsx extension

Answer (score 0):

May be the Quick Solution is..

```
  "start": "watchify ./src/js/* ./src/jsx/*.jsx -v -t babelify -o ./build/app/bundle.js"
```

in your Script add *.jsx